# Is there a way to calculate the length of an arry inside a function instead of pass in as parameter?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and here is a template selection sort function I wrote which takes in an array and it length as parameter.
"""

```
template <class T>
void mySort(T a[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {   
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (a[min]>a[j])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min!=i)
        {
            T tmp = a[min];
            a[min] = a[i];
            a[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are few things I'm confused about
First, I know if we pass in array in to a function, it is actually not the copy of this array, so what is whole concept behind this? Is that we pass in its reference or the pointer to first index?

Second, is it possible to calculate the length of this array inside this function instead of pass in as parameter?

Third, people been told me it is better to use char[] instead of string in c++, since char[] is more related to fundimental c and string is just STL in c++, so is it means for most part of my code, I should use char[] instead of string?

Comment: Forget that C-style arrays exist. Always use `std::array` or `std::vector` (that both know their `.size()`) instead. You'll make your life simpler and have fewer headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, I know if we pass in array in to a function, it is actually not the copy of this array, so what is whole concept behind this? Is that we pass in its reference or the pointer to first index?

It's a pointer to the first element. Even though you wrote `T a[]`, the language converts it to `T* a` in a function parameter. It's weird, but there we go; that's just how "passing an array by value" works (or doesn't work) in C and C++.

> Second, is it possible to calculate the length of this array inside this function instead of pass in as parameter?

No. The information is not available from the type, so it has to be passed as a separate argument.

Workarounds include passing the array itself by reference:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
void mySort(T (&a)[N]) {
```

…or passing a `std::array` or passing a `std::vector`, all of which "know" the dimension.

> Third, people been told me it is better to use char[] instead of string in c++, since char[] is more related to fundimental c and string is just STL in c++, so is it means for most part of my code, I should use char[] instead of string?

That's the opposite of the usual advice. Though using a `char` array is not evil, and can be done where you have some simple array for which you don't need dynamic allocation, `std::string` is far more flexible and easy to use, and should generally be your go-to tool for character arrays.

I don't know what "it's just STL in C++" means as an argument.

The usual conventions may not apply if you're doing "competitive programming" but, then, that's not real programming.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
template<class T, std::size_t n> void mySort(T (&a)[n]);
```

?